Why ReqRes response to my POST request doesn't return the values I included?
I'm learning about API etc., and I was trying to do a simple POST request to ReqRes.in. Although the POST response suggests that the request was successful, it doesn't include the data I'm sending, which is not the behavior expected according to the documentation...
My code:
<script>
function startAPI() {
  let xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhttp.status == 201) {
        let reqresponse = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        console.log(reqresponse)
      };
    };
  };
  let newUser = {
    name: document.querySelector("#userName").value,
    email: document.querySelector("#userEmail").value,
  };
  xhttp.open('POST', 'https://reqres.in/api/users', true);
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(newUser));
};
</script>
<body>
<form onsubmit="startAPI(); return false">
  <p>
    <label for="userName">Nome: </label>
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="userEmail">Email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="userEmail" id="userEmail">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create User">
  </p>
</form>
</body>

On submitting, I was expecting this response:

Object { name: "User Input Value", email: "Email Input Value", id: "848", createdAt: "2024-05-09T01:17:49.098Z" }

But what I receive is:

Object { id: "848", createdAt: "2024-05-09T01:17:49.098Z" }

I tested several combinations of ID, values capturing, methods of form submit, variables and function names, removal of If's in the function etc., nothing worked.
What am I doing wrong?

why are you expecting to receive the data you sent? You'd have to show the server code to show that it sends the received data back to you

Looks like the only thing you are missing is to set the "Content-type" header to json. Do this by adding the line:

xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json")

between the .open() and .send() calls.


function startAPI( ) {
  let xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhttp.status == 201) {
        let reqresponse = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        console.log(reqresponse);
      }
    }
  }
  let newUser = {
    name: document.querySelector("#userName").value,
    email: document.querySelector("#userEmail").value,
  };
  xhttp.open('POST', 'https://reqres.in/api/users', true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(newUser));
}
        <form onsubmit="startAPI(); return false">
          <p>
            <label for="userName">Nome: </label>
            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="userEmail">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" name="userEmail" id="userEmail">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create User">
          </p>
        </form>




Yep, that was exactly right. I'm taking JS lessons but the teacher never mentioned this... I guess it's time to change courses lol. Thanks!
